# Prevent anyone from sending email between local users

Tags: postfix

I'm trying to prevent anonymous users from potentially being able to send email from one local user to another. If someone knows the email addresses of 2 accounts on my postfix server (2.10.1) it seems that they are able to send email between them from anywhere without authenticating. I tested this using telnet commands:

220 domain1.co.uk ESMTP Postfix
ehlo domain1.co.uk
250-domain1.co.uk
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
MAIL FROM:user1@domain1.co.uk
250 2.1.0 Ok
RCPT TO:user1@domain2.co.uk
250 2.1.5 Ok
data
354 End data with .
test
.
250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as A002982019
quit
221 2.0.0 Bye

I want to avoid anyone from being able to send between local domains unless they are either authenticated or from specific IP addresses (local ones for relay).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `reject_sender_login_mismatch` or `reject_unauthenticated_sender_login_mismatch`, parameters for `smtpd_sender_restrictions`.

For example:

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_sender_login_mismatch, ...
```

From the [documentation](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sender_restrictions):

> reject_sender_login_mismatch
>
> Reject the request when $smtpd_sender_login_maps specifies an owner for the MAIL FROM address, but the client is not (SASL) logged in as that MAIL FROM address owner; or when the client is (SASL) logged in, but the client login name doesn't own the MAIL FROM address according to $smtpd_sender_login_maps.
>
> reject_unauthenticated_sender_login_mismatch
>
> Enforces the reject_sender_login_mismatch restriction for unauthenticated clients only. This feature is available in Postfix version 2.1 and later.

The former is *more* restrictive, prohibiting e.g. user1@example.com from sending mail as user2@example.com, even if authenticated. The latter will permit authenticated users to send mail from any email address.

---

`permit_mynetworks` should always appear first, and will allow anything from the IP addresses and CIDR ranges you specified in `mynetworks`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you are looking for with the following setup:

```
/etc/postfix/main.cf:
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mx_backup, reject_sender_login_mismatch
smtpd_sender_login_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/login_maps

cat /etc/postfix/login_maps
user@server.net user@server.net

# postmap /etc/postfix/login_maps
# systemctl restart postfix

Test 1: MAIL FROM: user@server.net   RCPT TO: user@server.net
nc smtp.server.net 25
220 smtp.server.net ESMTP - nice to meet you.
helo dude
250 smtp.server.net
mail from: <user@server.net>
250 2.1.0 Ok
rcpt to: <user@server.net>
553 5.7.1 <user@server.net>: Sender address rejected: not logged in
^]^C


Test 2: MAIL FROM: me@me.com    RCPT TO: user@server.net
nc smtp.server.net 25
220 smtp.server.net ESMTP - nice to meet you.
helo dude
250 smtp.server.net
mail from: <me@me.com>
250 2.1.0 Ok
rcpt to: <user@server.net>
250 2.1.5 Ok
data
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
helo
.
250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as CB96C3E82F
quit
221 2.0.0 Bye
```

More info at: http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html
http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sender_restrictions